# Increase 1/2'' copper water pipe to 3/4''

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, copper

I have a 3/4'' main that comes into the house and then reduces to 1/2''. Then all my fixtures run off that in series.
My thought is to i make it 3/4'' copper all the way and then run 1/2'' tees to each fixture.
For the hot, the pipes coming out of the water heater and boiler are 1/2". Can i leave them 1/2'' but then increase to 3/4'' to run to the bathrooms? Then 1/2'' tee to the fixtures?
Is there any problems or issues that with me doing it this way?

Comment: Do you have pressure issues now? A downside, longer time to get hot water to far bathrooms.

Comment: I have pressure issues when 2 fixtures are running at the same time. When I remodeled my 2nd floor bathroom last year, i used 3/4'' pex for the supply up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to increase the water flow to the fixtures in your house but do not want to re-pipe the whole house, you could increase the supply pipe from the 3/4" inlet to the water heater. Tee off any of the individual supplies from the new 3/4" supply with reducers and the final pipe into the hot water tank could stay 1/2". This way you would double the supply water available to all the fixtures since the hot and the cold will have individual supplies instead of a 1/2" supply supplying both the hot and cold. Also, remember that almost all sinks and toilets use a 3/8" supply and only the tub and/or shower and the laundry tub use a full size pipe.  Doing it your way would be fine.